# Azure Dev Spaces - There is no more space available for file synchronization

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

I try to use Azure Dev Spaces for an existing ASP.NET Core project that is already deployed to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-netcore-visualstudio) to enable Azure Dev Spaces for my project. However, when I try to debug my project using Azure Dev Spaces, I get the following error:

```
Enabling debugging...  There is no more space available for file synchronization. Please remove unused spaces by running 'azds down', reduce the size of your workspace, and retry later.
```

Running `azds down` doesn't solve my issue:

```
PS D:\sources\git\> azds down    
Identifying the dev space workload 'xxx'...
'myproject' does not identify any dev space workload.
```

If I try to invoke `azds up` in the command line, I also get an error:

```
Using dev space 'myresourcegroup' with target 'mycluster'
Synchronizing files...Oops... An unexpected error has occurred. A report of the error will be sent to Microsoft. Please include the following Client Request ID when contacting support: 5696f5ea-.....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This happens for me when the useGitIgnore property is set to false in the azds.yaml file.